# AFNetworking failure block

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

i'm using afnetworking 2.0 to show youtube videos.
When i have a connection error, i open an alert view and i'd like stop the request if i click "ok".

Alert view is showed correctly but when i click "ok" the request isn't stopped and i see activity indicator.

How can i stop the request?

This is the code below:

```
-(void)loadData {

NSString *urlAsString = @"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=wankel&v=2&max-results=50&alt=jsonc";

UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
activityIndicator.color = [UIColor blackColor];
activityIndicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2 );

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    self.moviesArray = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"data.items"];
    NSLog(@"%@", moviesArray);

    self.thumbnailsArray = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.thumbnail"];

    self.moviesDetailArray = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"data.items"];

    [activityIndicator setHidden:YES];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];


    [self.collectionView reloadData];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *alertView =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error.localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Try again", nil];
    [activityIndicator setHidden:YES];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];      
    [alertView show];           
    }];

[operation start];
}
```

Comment: Try googling "afnetworking stop request". There are already several Stack Overflow questions for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the operation to a **AFHTTPRequestOperationManager** ?
The manager has an operationQueue property. You can cancel operations from there.

When the operation fails, stop the operation from the shared manager.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

Edit:
If you're looking for a specific operation you can iterate through the operations in the queue:

```
for (NSOperation *operation in manager.operationQueue.operations) {
    // check if this is the right operation, and cancel it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting

```
[operation cancel];
```

in your failure block